# Recording MIDI files with a digital piano on Android

Tags: midi, digital-piano, midi-controller-keyboard

I have a digital Yahama piano with a MIDI out port. I would like to record a MIDI file by playing the piano, connecting the piano with an Android (or Raspberry Pi) device. Once the MIDI file is made, I can edit it on a more powerful device.

My biggest question is what's the best way to connect the piano? The most simple solution looks like a MIDI tot (micro)USB cable like [this](https://www.bol.com/nl/p/dolphix-usb-midi-input-midi-output-kabel-1-8-meter/9200000083626226/?suggestionType=typedsearch&bltgh=nG25Uv5UMC4lRMXTmwNLBA.1.2.ProductTitle) one, but these cables get often a bad review.

Anyone has any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

MIDI-USB adapter cables are indeed the way to go, and I actually own that same exact cable you linked for my home recording setup and it's worked fine for me over the last several years.

One thing to be aware of is that some keyboard models won't output the MIDI if you have other outputs plugged in (like line-out), so if you're not getting the signal as expected on the receiving device try unplugging any other keyboard outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Those with the pseudo note clef on them tend to make MIDI fall apart under polyphony and will not transmit larger batches of stuff like SysEx dumps (used for saving and restoring settings and other stuff) without error.  You tend to be better off with ancient brand adapters.  For most purposes, USB1.1 (12Mbps) is fine, though avoid the use of hubs (unless they have more than a single transaction translator but that kind of information is hard to get).